# "Only" or "rules" keywords weirdly remove jobs from the CI pipeline

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, continuous-deployment, cicd

I am trying to use "rules" and "only" keywords to define my pipeline behaviors between merge requests, pushes into **dev** branch and pushes into **master** branch.

I noticed several weird behaviors in the Gitlab CI, let's see in my merge_requests pipelines.

- With this **gitlab-ci.yml** file, without any rule, all the jobs are displayed and run.

```yaml
image: "python:3.8"


stages:
  - test_without_only_policy
  - test_with_only_policy

test_without_only_policy:
  stage: test_without_only_policy
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "Yay, I am in the pipeline"

test_with_only_policy:
  stage: test_with_only_policy
  script:
  - echo "I am always in the pipeline"
```

[image: both jobs appear when there are no rules]

Everything is working as expected, great

- With this **gitlab-ci.yml** file, without an "only" policy in the 2nd job, the 1st job without rules disappears.

```yaml
image: "python:3.8"

stages:
  - test_without_only_policy
  - test_with_only_policy

test_without_only_policy:
  stage: test_without_only_policy
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "No, I am not in the pipeline anymore"

test_with_only_policy:
  stage: test_with_only_policy
  only:
  - merge_requests
  script:
  - echo "I am always in the pipeline"
```

[image: the job without "only" policy disappears]

Why did the 1st job without the rules or "only" policy disappear?

- With this **gitlab-ci.yml** file, with a "rules" keyword in the 2nd job, the 1st job without rules disappears.

```yaml
image: "python:3.8"

stages:
  - test_without_only_policy
  - test_with_only_policy

test_without_only_policy:
  stage: test_without_only_policy
  when: manual
  script:
    - echo "No, I am not in the pipeline anymore"

test_with_only_policy:
  stage: test_with_only_policy
  rules:
  - if: '$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "merge_request_event"'
    when: manual
  script:
  - echo "I am always in the pipeline"
```

[image: the job without "rules" keyword disappears]

Why did the 1st job without the rules or "only" policy disappear?

Thank you for your help, I don't understand why my job disappears when I add rules in other jobs.

Answer (score 9):

According to [the documentation for Merge Request Pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html#use-only-or-except-to-run-pipelines-for-merge-requests), if you have a pipeline where only some jobs use only/except/rules with `merge_requests`, only those jobs will be in the pipeline if it is a Merge Request pipeline. The other jobs will be left out.

Here's the example from the docs:

```yaml
build:
  stage: build
  script: ./build
  only:
    - main

test:
  stage: test
  script: ./test
  only:
    - merge_requests

deploy:
  stage: deploy
  script: ./deploy
  only:
    - main
```

In this example, the only job that specifies it should run for Merge Request pipelines is the `test` job. For standard `push` pipelines, the `build` and `deploy` jobs will run, but when a new merge request is created, a change is pushed to a branch that is the source branch on an existing merge request, or you hit the Run Pipeline button on the Pipelines tab for a Merge Request, it will run a Merge Request pipeline.

Here's another example with a different scenario:

```yaml
A:
  stage: some_stage
  only:
    - branches
    - tags
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - script.sh

B: 
  stage: some_other_stage
  only:
    - branches
    - tags
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - script.sh

C: 
  stage: third_stage
  only:
    - merge_requests
  script:
    - script.sh
```

In this example, jobs `A` and `B` run for all pipeline types `push`, `tags`, `merge_requests`, etc., but job `C` only runs for `merge_request` pipelines.

That's why your `test_without_only_policy` job will never be in a pipeline where `test_with_only_policy` runs. `test_with_only_policy` specifically runs for Merge Request events, but `test_without_only_policy` does not.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This is an unusual behavior I think but as you said, the documentation specifies:
"When you use only: [merge_requests], only jobs with that keyword are run in the context of a merge request. No other jobs run."

Comment: The docs for gitlab 15.0 and later no longer have this wording; I wonder if this behavior has changed?

Comment: I'm still seeing this behavior in 15.10.6.